# .net core 3.1 Blazor WebAssembly: does not contain a definition for "LoginMode"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am currently trying to change the default of popup to redirect upon logging in.
I am using .NETCORE 3.1 Blazor WebAssembly any help would be great! Thanks!

[code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1aHS.png)

[csproj packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydgTx.png)

Comment: Any update? Does my reply has helped you?

Comment: @BrandoZhang Yes your solution is correct.  I upvoted you.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this github [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20374) that the redirect mode only supported in the asp.net core 5.0.

If your application is 3.1, it will not work well.

If you migrate to 5.0, then you could use below codes to use redirect instead of popup.

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    ...
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
});
```

More details ,you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-5.0#login-mode).

Comment: Thanks brando your absolutely correct I updated shortly after posting.  I make sure to vote up your post because you are indeed correct.

Comment: If you feel my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer, so that other folks who faces the same issue could find the solution more easily. Thank you. About how to mark as answer, you could refer to this [article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).